# Can't get object data from class instance in ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

How can I get the data out of my class instance? I can get this:

```
instance = MyModule::MyClass.new(obj1, obj2)

puts instance
#=> #<MyModule::MyClass:0x0000010120de68>

puts instance.inspect 
#=>  #<MyModule::MyClass:0x000001019157b0 @obj1=#<MyModule::MyOtherClass:0x00000101915b20 @obj=["stuff", "more stuff", "things"]>, @obj2=#<MyModule::MyThirdClass:0x00000101915a80 @obj=["more things", "even more"]>>
```

I thought I could just do instance.obj1 and get the @obj array from this.  This gives me "undefined method."  What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access instance variables from the outside by default:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end
end

foo = Foo.new(123) #<Foo:0x007fdc312205f0 @obj=123>
foo.obj            # undefined method `obj' ... (NoMethodError)
```

You have to create a getter to do so, e.g. via [`attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader):

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :obj

  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end
end

foo = Foo.new(123)
foo.obj            #=> 123
```

Comment: But I do have accessors!

Comment: I figured it out.  There were 3 classes involved. The class that took the other 2 classes as parameters had attr_accessors, but the other classes with the variables I wanted to expose, did not have any getter/setter.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to post your class definition for us to be certain what the problem is, but I'm guessing that you didn't define attribute getters/setters for your objects. Because of the way the Ruby variable scoping works, instance variables are localized to the inner scope of the object instance (meaning that they are only accessible within method definitions within the class definition).

To access these variables from outside the scope of the class definition, you must define attribute getters and setters, with are methods that expose these variables to the outer scope:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  # attribute getter for @name
  def name
    @name
  end

  # attribute setter for @name
  def name=(n)
    @name = n
  end
end
```

This is such a common pattern that Ruby has provided helper methods for defining setters and getters for instance variables: `attr_reader`, `attr_writer`, and `attr_accessor`.

- `attr_reader` takes one or more symbols as arguments (which correspond to the instance variables you wish to target) and creates *getter* methods for each.
- `attr_writer` takes the same list of symbols as `attr_reader` but creates *setter* methods for each instance variable name passed as an argument
- `attr_accessor` generates both *setter* **and** *getter* methods for the instance variables named.

```
class Bar
  attr_reader :name   # only allow reading of @name
  attr_accessor :rank, :age  # enable both reading and writing of @rank and @age

  def initialize(name, rank, age)
    @name = name
    @rank = rank
    @age = age
  end
end

b = Bar.new('Jack BeLucky', 'Corporal', 32)
b.name
=> 'Jack BeLucky'
b.age 
=> 32
b.age += 1
b.age
=> 33
```